# Calculating the limit of a complex function: $\lim_{z \to 0}$ $\frac {\sin(wz)}{\sin(z)}, w \in \mathbb{C} $

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, limits

$\lim_{z \to 0}$ $\frac {\sin(wz)}{\sin(z)}, w \in \mathbb{C}$

Should I convert it to a power series? Or would I be better off switching $\sin$ to it's complex equivalent $\sin(y) = \frac{ e^{iy} − e ^{-iy}}{2i} $?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MacLaurin expansion
$$\sin(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{(2n+1)!}z^{2n+1}=z-\frac{z^3}{3!}+\frac{z^5}{5!}-+\ldots$$
might be the best approach. As $z\to0$, the terms with exponents become meaningless (try substituting $10^{-3}$), and you can safely use $\sin(\alpha z)\approx\alpha z$.  Of course, more terms can be included, the result follows similarly:

$\lim_{z\to0}\dfrac{\sin(wz)}{\sin(z)}=\lim_{z\to0}\dfrac{wz+\frac{w^3z^3}{3!}+O((wz)^5)}{z+\frac{z^3}{3!}+O(z^5)}=\lim_{z\to0} \dfrac{w+\frac{w^3z^2}{3!}+\frac{1}{z}O((wz)^5)}{1+\frac{z^2}{3!}+O(z^4)}=w$.

Using the fact $\lim_{z\to0}\dfrac{\sin z}{z}=1\iff\sin\alpha z\approx\alpha z$ works as well.

Answer (score 1):

Using power series, we see that $\sin(wz)=wz+O(|z|^2)$ as $z\to 0$, and thus
$$
\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\sin(wz)}{\sin z}=w.
$$

Comment: I don't get it. Would you care explaining it to me how the power series of $\sin(wz)$ works?

Answer (score 1):

Why not to write $$\frac {\sin(wz)}{\sin(z)}=\frac {\sin(wz)}{wz} \frac z{\sin(z)}w$$

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{sin(wz)}{sin(z)}=\frac{wz-\frac{w^3z^3}{6}+O(z^6)}{z(1-\frac{z^2}{6}+O(z^5))}=\frac{wz-\frac{w^3z^3}{6}+O(z^6)}{z}(1+O(z^2))=(w+O(z^2))$

sending $z$ to zero you get $w$.